# Change the safari location.

Tags: selenium, safari, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to Safari and when I give :

```
new SafariDriver()
```

I get :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The expected Safari data directory does not exist: /Users/root/Library/Safari
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:177)
    at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariExtensions.getInstallDirectory(SafariExtensions.java:179)
    at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariExtensions.install(SafariExtensions.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor.start(SafariDriverCommandExecutor.java:95)
    at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver.startClient(SafariDriver.java:73)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:112)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:127)
    at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver.<init>(SafariDriver.java:59)
    at org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver.<init>(SafariDriver.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:102)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:57)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:190)
    at com.apple.ist.ets.monsoon.test.ProfilePage.workAround(ProfilePage.groovy:79)
    at com.apple.ist.ets.monsoon.test.ProfilePage.initWebContext(ProfilePage.groovy:88)
    at com.apple.ist.ets.test.BaseWebTest.setUp(BaseWebTest.java:67)
    at com.apple.ist.ets.test.BaseJUnitTestCase.preMethod(BaseJUnitTestCase.java:936)
    at com.apple.ist.ets.test.TestCase.preProcess(TestCase.java:495)
    at com.apple.ist.ets.test.ExecutionComponent.run(ExecutionComponent.java:1481)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:206)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

I tried even the following:

```
        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability("safari.dataDir","/Users/me/Library/Safari")
        driver = new SafariDriver(cap);
```

But facing the same issue. Where I'm making mistake?

Thanks.

Comment: Is directory "/Users/me/Library/Safari" available in your system?

Comment: @batman some additional information for this question would be useful

Comment: @MarshallTigerus: what information? I tried the following it seems to be not working.

Comment: is the directory "/Users/me/Library/Safari" on your system?

Comment: where is the safari library located on your system?

Comment: its in the location `/Users/me/Library/Safari`

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a known issue.

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5293

Does the folder you are searching for even exist?

Comment: Love the random downvote for linking the EXACT ISSUE.  I wonder why I bother on this hate filled website

Answer (score 0):

When launching the hub and node, don't use 'sudo' as this would search for Safari at the root level, but you might have installed Safari under your login user name.

If you are admin on your Mac, try simply 'java -jar selenium-standalone.x.x.x.jar -role hub' from the account where you logged in to install latest OSX update/safari